# GFCI Circuit - Open Neutral But Not Tripped

Tags: electrical

I have a GFCI circuit in my kitchen with two outlets, one GFCI/AFCI and one normal outlet (>6ft from water source). It has worked fine for the 10 months I've owned the house, but suddenly the normal outlet on the circuit isn't working. With an outlet tester, I get correct wiring for both plugs on the GFCI, but open neutral on both plugs of the normal outlet. I pulled both outlets and the wires are secure and not shorting. I also tried the obvious of testing/resetting the GFCI. Also, plugging something into the GFCI outlet works without issue, it's only the normal outlet on the same circuit that has issues. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Additional note: I tested the continuity between various points of the circuit, and the only thing that stood out to me is that the two neutral screws on the GFCI are not continuous with each other. Is that normal? The two hot screws are. And yes, I tried testing/resetting the GFCI.

Comment: I take it the outlet tester goes dark completely when you plug it into the normal outlet then hit TEST on the GFCI?

Comment: "Open neutral", "open ground" and "correct", are the only readouts on those 3-light testers that are reliable. The red-yellow-yellow lights are reliable, but the label is written for detecting "incorrect installation* in new house builds.  Its advice when looking for *failures* in old wiring is frustratingly misleading for other indications.

Answer (score 0):

If suspecting no neutral continuity within the GFI then disconnect both load wires and carefully test the hot to neutral voltage of the load screws.  Then if it shows no potential you would need a new GFI.

On the other hand, if it shows normal voltage it might simply mean you were earlier trying to test the continuity of a grounded conductor.

If the GFI is working normally then you might have a loose or damaged cable somewhere.